# Selected Index and Cell Value in Detail SubForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to implement a very simple subform document grid on a form:

[image]

I have everything except getting the file path when the user clicks the grid.  How can I get the filepath value from the user row click event ?

Sorry if my terminology is off I rarely write vba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a public subroutine that references your `FilePath` field and then reference this subroutine in the on-click event of each of the fields on your subform.

So if your subform looks like this:

[image]

Go in to Design View of the form, and select one of your fields:

[image]

With a field selected, go to the Property Sheet on the right-hand side and go to the Event tab and click the [...] button on the On Click event:

[image]

You'll be taken to the form's VBA script module and it'll create the initial VBA for the on-click event of the field you selected:

[image]

Ignore that field's on-click event VBA for now, and instead move your cursor to the top and make some room for a public subroutine above the field's on-click event.

Write something like this at the top:

```vb
Public Sub GetFilePath()

    Debug.Print Me.FilePath

End Sub
```

So your code in Access should now look something like this:

[image]

That public sub I've called `GetFilePath` can now be referenced in the on-click event of every field in your subform. Let's finish the on-click event of the ID field that we just started...

[image]

...and also reference the same public sub in every other field's on-click event (again, by selecting the field in Design View and then clicking [...] button in Property Sheet's on-click event):

[image]

In the VBA editor, make sure you have the Immediate Window open; it should be in the area below your VBA code. If it's not there press Ctrl + G or go to View > Immediate Window:

[image]

With the VBA editor and Immediate Window still open, go back to your form and put it into Form View.

Click on any row and you should see the `FilePath` data for the row you've clicked on print out in the Immediate Window (this is what `Debug.Print` does):

[image]

You probably don't want the `FilePath` to go the Immediate Window, but as you haven't specified where you want it to go I figured this would at least illustrate how you can get at that data by clicking on a record in your subform.

All you need to do is replace the `Debug.Print Me.FilePath` line to whatever is useful to you.

Hope this was enough to get you started though :)

Comment: Thankyou so much this is one of the most detailed answers I have ever received on SO.  I wish I could upvote it more !

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

MS Access does not provide Row click event. You have to either perform, [Form onClick Event] or ideally make the filePath as HyperLink and onClicking FilePath retrieve its value.

When you go for [Form onClick event] you will get the FilePath from selected row. But the click event is only fired if you are clicking the form and none of the fields.

As above mentioned, make the FilePAth field as hyperlink, add onClick event to it and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for upwarming but the accepted answer is not the best way to go.

Instead of creating an OnClick-event for every column in that subform (for each control),
you should rather use the OnCurrent event of the Subform itself, which is triggered whenever you change the current record. This basically happens whenever you click on another row in the subform.
Doing so will save you work whenever you extend the subform with a new column.

in that OnCurrent Event of the Subform you will then have the same code.

Basically it should look like this:

```
Public Sub Form_Current()
    Debug.Print Me.FilePath
End Sub
```